# Creating a reactive data frame for shiny: object 'input' not found

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I'm building a shiny application that works off a single data frame to populate a set of plots with drop down menus for simple filtering.  The original setup calls a defined plot generation function that passes in the data frame as an argument, performs filtering -> aggregation -> plot output.  I'm hoping to increase performance by passing a reactive data frame into my plotting functions so that the filtering/aggregating only needs to occur once, instead of 6 times for each individual plot.  Here's an example of how I'm attempting to go about this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

### Data ###

colA <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
colB <- c("w", "x", "y", "z")
colC <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

testDF <- data.frame(colA, colB, colC)

reactiveTestDF <- reactive({
    testDF %>%
        filter(colA == input$filterDropDown)
})

### Application UI ###

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("test"),

    # Sidebar filter dropdown
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("filterDropDown", "filters", choices = c("A", "B"))
            )
        ,

        # Show data frame
        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("testTable")
        )
    )
)

### App Server ###

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$testTable <- renderTable(reactiveTestDF())
    #output$testTable <- renderTable(testDF)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I receive this error when running the app above (the commented out line runs perfectly fine):

```
Warning: Error in : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `colA == input$filterDropDown`.
x object 'input' not found
  126: <Anonymous>
```

Is this the correct way to go about creating a data frame that filters itself based on input parameters(drop down lists in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to move the `reactive` part into `server`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

### Data ###

colA <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
colB <- c("w", "x", "y", "z")
colC <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

testDF <- data.frame(colA, colB, colC)


### Application UI ###

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("test"),
  
  # Sidebar filter dropdown
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("filterDropDown", "filters", choices = c("A", "B"))
    )
    ,
    
    # Show data frame
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("testTable")
    )
  )
)

### App Server ###

server <- function(input, output) {
  reactiveTestDF <- reactive({
    testDF %>%
      filter(colA == input$filterDropDown)
  })
  
  output$testTable <- renderTable(reactiveTestDF())
 
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```